# New array counter within nested loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am studying JavaScript and I believe I understand how these loops work. However, I got an exercise where I didn't understand which was the function of the counter for a new array being filled. This is the exercise:

```js
var animals = ["goat", "cat", "crow"];
var products = ["milk", "cheese", "burger"];
var foodItems = [];
var k = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
    foodItems[k] = animals[i] + products[j];
    k++;
  }
}

console.log(foodItems);
```

The code above produces the array `["goatmilk", "goatcheese", "goatburger", "catmilk", "catcheese", "catburger", "crowmilk", "crowcheese", "crowburger"]`. If I take out the [k] counter, it gives me an 1 element array `[crowburger]`; if I put a zero as the `foodItems` counter, it gives me `[crowburger]` as well, but bigger numbers produce `undefined` elements in the array before `crowburger` (i.e. `foodItems[10]` equals `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "crowburger"]`).

My question: what does the [k] counter do and why if it is replaced by numbers it produces `undefined` elements plus `[crowburger?]`

Comment: why would you take it out, you have an array and you need indexes to put those elements to certain positions... you should study arrays in JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k` is the *index* of the *array*. An *array* is a sorted list of elements and the standard access is to use an *index* to get the element at the given *index*. *index* is zero based, it starts from zero for the first element of the *array*.

If you take always the same index, the element at the given index is replaced by the new element.

The pattern

```
array[index] = value:
index++;
```

is like [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which add the element at the end of the array without maintaining an index by hand.

```
array.push(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `k` is the outer iterator. It's controlling the index of the global `foodItems` empty array, because if you declared it inside the scope of the loop, it wouldn't be accessible outside of the loop, and would vanish. So, commonly, you declare the outer array and iterator, and as you iterate through the loop, you're adding the values to the array and iterating over it.

Think of it like this:

var k = 0 // So we start on the *first* index of the foodItems array
var foodItems = []; // So it is declared empty at start

Here's what it's basically doing:

foodItems[k] (which is currently zero) is equal to animals[0] + products[0]... Then foodItems[1] is animals[0] + products[1] and so on.

The reason you can't use any number is because it doesn't have any indices when it starts, and you can't access the 5th (for example) element of an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The k counter is the index of the foodItems - In your case it cannot go higher than 9 which is 3x3.

So first time around you have k=0

```
foodItems[0] = "goat"+"milk"
```

second k++ (increment k by one)

```
foodItems[1] = "goat"+"cheese"
```

If you do not want the counter, just [push to foodItems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

i.e change `foodItems[k] = animals[i] + products[j];` to `foodItems.push(animals[i] + products[j]);`

It will add the string to a new empty spot in foodItems on each push, making foodItems longer for each push

```js
var animals = ["goat", "cat", "crow"];
var products = ["milk", "cheese", "burger"];
var foodItems = [];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
    foodItems.push(animals[i] + products[j]);
  }
}

console.log(foodItems);
```